# URL Rewrite and Archive Template Files - Post Type vs. Taxonomy

Tags: url-rewriting, archives, rewrite-rules, custom-post-type-archives, template-hierarchy

I apologize if this is a difficult question to understand, but really it's a template hierarchy / rewrites question.

I have set up a few rewrite rules that are successful, but I'm hoping that I can manipulate them to call different template files in the hierarchy, so I can control archive pages more logically. I have a team-news custom post type, and a sport taxonomy. My goal is to have a team-news archive of posts only from a specific sport, and a separate sport archive for all posts and pages associated with that taxonomy. Unfortunately, I'm only able to access the sport taxonomy archive with my current rewrites, not the team-news CPT archive.

Here are my rewrite rules and an explanation of what I think happens:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^athletics/team/([^/]*)/news/?','index.php?post_type=team-news&sport=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

This one brings up `taxonomy-sport.php`, although I was hoping it would bring up `archive-team-news.php`. I need the `sport=` part, because I only want to show team-news posts for that sport.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^athletics/sport/([^/]*)/?','index.php?sport=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

This one rightly brings up `taxonomy-sport.php` as I had hoped.

According to the Query Monitor plugin, the template hierarchy when requesting the url `/athletics/team/varsity-football/news/` is this:

1. taxonomy-sport-varsity-football.php
2. taxonomy-sport.php  --- The one it's using
3. taxonomy.php
4. archive-team-news.php --- The one I want it to be
5. archive.php
6. index.php

Is there any way to make archive-team-news.php work for that URL? Would I need to [filter the hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy)? I'm pretty new to WP, so I don't want to change up too much...

**EDIT 1:** 
To simplify my goal --

`?post_type=[1]&taxonomy=[2]` will always pull up a **taxonomy** archive page, as far as I can tell. Can I make it pull up the **post-type** archive page instead?

**EDIT 2:** 
I've changed the 2nd parameter of the first rewrite rule to `'index.php?post_type=team-news'`, and now the correct archive page is being displayed (`archive-team-news.php`) but I still need to filter further by taxonomy somehow.

NOTE: the taxonomy slug is in the URL as `athletics/team/[taxonomy]/news/`, so now I'm trying to [parse the URL for that value in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1772870/4107296), but I'd prefer a WP solution (less hacky).

Comment: if you change the order in URL, does it change something `index.php?sport=$matches[1]&post_type=team-news` ?

Comment: Good idea, but no. That's what I had at first, so I thought if I "prioritized" the post type by putting it first, it might work, but it didn't. :/

Comment: One thing you can try is to use a custom query var to pass the tax slug, then hook pre_get_posts to manually add the tax query. Another possible solution is to hook parse_query and force a post type archive. You could filter the hierarchy as you mention, but it’ll still be identified as a tax archive in things like body_class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled this with a pre_get_posts hook (thanks, @Milo), passing in the URL part that corresponds to the slug I need. Hope this helps someone down the road. Improvements are welcome. Thanks.

```
function filter_team_news_archives_by_sport_taxonomy($query) {

    if (is_post_type_archive('team-news') && $query->is_main_query()){

            // Get $sport_slug from URL  --  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36002190/4107296
            $url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
            $parsed = parse_url( $url );
            $chunks = explode( '/', trim($parsed['path'],'/') );
            // if the URL is in this format: /athletics/team/[sport-slug]/news 
            if ($chunks[0] === 'athletics' && $chunks[1] === 'team' && $chunks[3] === 'news') {
                $sport_slug = $chunks[2];
                $query->set('tax_query', array(array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'sport',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $sport_slug,
                )));
            }
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_team_news_archives_by_sport_taxonomy');
```